# PHP - how to differentiate between posts of the same user?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a posting system; I can display a list of all created posts, and when clicked on it can take you to a new page displaying the correct post and its information (if the user created only one post), via using a $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']. thing is the string I'm using to differentiate between posts is the username of the creator of the post, and is stored in the post upon creation as 'post_uid' which == user_uid. so now if the user has created multiple posts, each post displayed on the anchor list page when clicked on, will just pull its variables from the 1st post created from the user, not the new one's. any suggestions on how to get around this would be much appreciated.

here is my code for the list of posts to click on:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY post_id";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$i = 0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
       if($i==15) break;
        $post_title = $row['post_title'];
        $post_uid = $row['post_uid'];
        $updated = $row['post_updated'];
        echo '<br><h1><a href="./post-select-brief.php?'.$post_uid.'">'. 
        $post_title .', price: '. $row['post_price'] .'</a></h1></br>';
        $i++;


}
```

here is my code for the full post:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_uid 
='".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']."'");

$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);

$uid = ucfirst($row2['post_uid']); 

$rating = $row2['rating'];

stating varibales etc etc....
```

thankyou for any help you can give!

Comment: Well, the obvious suggestion is to not do it that way.  Why would you make the userId be the unique ID for the post?  Give the post its own ID.

Comment: the post has an auto increment id, but how do i link it to the user who created it, as i also need to display his/her information

Comment: Assign a `userId` or `createdBy` or some similar value on the row.  Then join on the `User` table (or whatever you happen to call it).  I suggest you look at any of the many CMS applications that are out there to get an idea of the common architecture strategies for these kind of systems.

Comment: oh great! thankyou!